# Need help for SQL Server cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have this table:

[image: Main Table]

And I want this output:

[image: Required Output]

I am using this code

```
DECLARE @InvoiceNo Varchar(100)
SET @InvoiceNo = '17-18/1003'

DECLARE @srNO Varchar(100)
PRINT @InvoiceNo

BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE #tempTableNew 
    (
        SrNO Varchar(100),
        Description Varchar(100),
        Qnty Varchar(100),
        Unit Varchar(100),
        Rate Varchar(100),
        Amount Varchar(100)
    )

    DECLARE CREATFINALTABLE CURSOR FOR
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY B.InvoiceNo ASC) AS 'SrNo'
        FROM 
            Billing B
        INNER JOIN 
            Furniture F on F.FurnitureID = B.ProductID
        WHERE
            B.InvoiceNo = @InvoiceNo  

    OPEN CREATFINALTABLE   
    FETCH NEXT FROM CREATFINALTABLE INTO @srNO

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    BEGIN   
        SELECT
            CONVERT(varchar, @srNO) AS 'SrNo',
            F.FurnitureName AS 'Description',
            CONVERT(varchar, B.Quantity) AS 'Qnty',
            CONVERT(varchar, U.UnitName) AS 'Unit',
            CONVERT(varchar, B.Rate) AS 'Rate',
            CONVERT(varchar, B.Amount) AS 'Amount' 
        INTO 
            #tempTable
        FROM
            Billing B
        INNER JOIN 
            Furniture F on F.FurnitureID = B.ProductID
        INNER JOIN 
            UnitMaster U ON U.UnitID = B.UnitID
        WHERE
            B.BillingID = @srNO

        INSERT INTO #tempTableNew
            SELECT * 
            FROM #tempTable
            WHERE SrNo = @srNO
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 
                (@srNO) AS 'srNo', 
                ('SIZE: ' + CONVERT(varchar, Length) + ' X' + 
                 CONVERT(varchar, Breadth) + ' X' + CONVERT(varchar, Height)) AS '[Description]',
                ' ' AS 'Qnty', ' ' AS 'Unit', ' ' AS 'Rate', ' ' AS 'Amount' 
            FROM Billing
            WHERE BillingID = @srNO
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 
                (@srNO) AS 'srNo', 
                'SPECS:' AS '[Description]', 
                ' ' AS 'Qnty', ' ' AS 'Unit', ' ' AS 'Rate', ' ' AS 'Amount' 
            FROM #tempTable
            WHERE SrNo = @srNO

           FETCH NEXT FROM CREATFINALTABLE INTO @srNO 

           DROP TABLE #tempTable
    END   

    SELECT * 
    INTO #formated 
    FROM #tempTableNew

    SELECT * FROM #formated

    DROP TABLE #tempTableNew
    DROP Table #formated

    CLOSE CREATFINALTABLE   
    DEALLOCATE CREATFINALTABLE
END
```

And I am getting this output. Please help me to get required output. I want to display records based on group by `AreaOfUsage`. Help me to modify this cursor so that I can get my required output. Thank you in advance..

[image: Current Output]

---

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE Product 
  ([SrNo] int, [Description] varchar(100), [Size] varchar(100)
, [Specs] varchar(100), [Qnty] int, [Unit] varchar(5)
, [Rate] int, [Amount] int, [AreaOfUsage] varchar(100)) 
; 

INSERT INTO Product 
([SrNo], [Description],[Size], [Specs], [Qnty], [Unit], [Rate], [Amount], [AreaOfUsage]) 
VALUES 
 (1, 'Bed as per design and detail', 'test iu','7.00x4.00x2.00', 1, 'P.RFT', 35000, 35000, 'Bedroom'),
 (2, 'Coffee Table as per design and detail', 'shdjh test','7.00x3.00x2.00', 1, 'P.RFT', 12500, 12500, 'Hall'),
 (3, 'Day Bed as per design in white', 'day bed test','7.00x5.00x3.00', 1, 'P.RFT', 19630, 19630, 'Bedroom') 
 ;
```

Comment: `1. SQL is NOT a "report writer" and that is what you are expecting it to do.`  Normally this level of presentation is undertaken in the "presentation layer" or he "report writer" 2. Please provide sample data AS TEXT we can reuse (or as inserts)  please please please don't use images of data

Comment: where does "size" come from? does not seem to exist in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extent of data manipulation isn't well suited to SQL and would normally be performed in a "presentation layer" but here is an approach that you may find helpful that does not require use of a cursor at all. It using CROSS APPLY with VALUES instead which creates multiple rows of output for each input row. The visual layout of the VALUES area is simple to control.

---

**REVISED ANSWER**

Available at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e2e50/1) as a demonstration.

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Product 
  ([SrNo] int, [Description] varchar(100), [Size] varchar(100)
, [Specs] varchar(100), [Qnty] int, [Unit] varchar(5)
, [Rate] int, [Amount] int, [AreaOfUsage] varchar(100)) 
; 

INSERT INTO Product 
([SrNo], [Description],[Size], [Specs], [Qnty], [Unit], [Rate], [Amount], [AreaOfUsage]) 
VALUES 
 (1, 'Bed as per design and detail', 'test iu','7.00x4.00x2.00', 1, 'P.RFT', 35000, 35000, 'Bedroom'),
 (2, 'Coffee Table as per design and detail', 'shdjh test','7.00x3.00x2.00', 1, 'P.RFT', 12500, 12500, 'Hall'),
 (3, 'Day Bed as per design in white', 'day bed test','7.00x5.00x3.00', 1, 'P.RFT', 19630, 19630, 'Bedroom') 
 ;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
      CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN concat(t.srNo, '') ELSE '' END   srNo
    , t.Description
    , CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN concat(t.Qnty, '') ELSE '' END   Qnty
    , CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN concat(t.Unit, '') ELSE '' END   Unit
    , CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN concat(t.Rate, '') ELSE '' END   Rate
    , CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN concat(t.Amount, '') ELSE '' END Amount
FROM (
      SELECT
              p.*
            , row_number() over(partition by AreaOfUsage
                                order by srNo, rn) as grporder
      FROM (
          SELECT
                AreaOfUsage
              , srNo
              , ca.rn
              , ca.Description
              , Qnty
              , Unit
              , Rate
              , Amount
          FROM Product
          CROSS APPLY (
                      VALUES
                            (1, AreaOfUsage),
                            (2, Description),
                            (3, Specs),
                            (4, Size)
                      ) ca (rn, description)
            ) p
      ) t
WHERE (
           (grporder = 1 )
        OR (grporder > 1 and AreaOfUsage <> Description)
      )  
ORDER BY AreaOfUsage, grporder
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e2e50/1/0)**:

```
| srNo |                           Description | Qnty |  Unit |  Rate | Amount |
|------|---------------------------------------|------|-------|-------|--------|
|      |                               Bedroom |      |       |       |        |
|    1 |          Bed as per design and detail |    1 | P.RFT | 35000 |  35000 |
|      |                        7.00x4.00x2.00 |      |       |       |        |
|      |                               test iu |      |       |       |        |
|    3 |        Day Bed as per design in white |    1 | P.RFT | 19630 |  19630 |
|      |                        7.00x5.00x3.00 |      |       |       |        |
|      |                          day bed test |      |       |       |        |
|      |                                  Hall |      |       |       |        |
|    2 | Coffee Table as per design and detail |    1 | P.RFT | 12500 |  12500 |
|      |                        7.00x3.00x2.00 |      |       |       |        |
|      |                            shdjh test |      |       |       |        |
```

**Query 2**:

Display of the detail rows to assist understanding

```
      SELECT
              p.*
            , row_number() over(partition by AreaOfUsage
                                order by srNo, rn) as grporder
      FROM (
          SELECT
                AreaOfUsage
              , srNo
              , ca.rn
              , ca.Description
              , Qnty
              , Unit
              , Rate
              , Amount
          FROM Product
          CROSS APPLY (
                      VALUES
                            (1, AreaOfUsage),
                            (2, Description),
                            (3, Specs),
                            (4, Size)
                      ) ca (rn, description)
            ) p
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e2e50/1/1)**:

```
| AreaOfUsage | srNo | rn |                           Description | Qnty |  Unit |  Rate | Amount | grporder |
|-------------|------|----|---------------------------------------|------|-------|-------|--------|----------|
|     Bedroom |    1 |  1 |                               Bedroom |    1 | P.RFT | 35000 |  35000 |        1 |
|     Bedroom |    1 |  2 |          Bed as per design and detail |    1 | P.RFT | 35000 |  35000 |        2 |
|     Bedroom |    1 |  3 |                        7.00x4.00x2.00 |    1 | P.RFT | 35000 |  35000 |        3 |
|     Bedroom |    1 |  4 |                               test iu |    1 | P.RFT | 35000 |  35000 |        4 |
|     Bedroom |    3 |  1 |                               Bedroom |    1 | P.RFT | 19630 |  19630 |        5 |
|     Bedroom |    3 |  2 |        Day Bed as per design in white |    1 | P.RFT | 19630 |  19630 |        6 |
|     Bedroom |    3 |  3 |                        7.00x5.00x3.00 |    1 | P.RFT | 19630 |  19630 |        7 |
|     Bedroom |    3 |  4 |                          day bed test |    1 | P.RFT | 19630 |  19630 |        8 |
|        Hall |    2 |  1 |                                  Hall |    1 | P.RFT | 12500 |  12500 |        1 |
|        Hall |    2 |  2 | Coffee Table as per design and detail |    1 | P.RFT | 12500 |  12500 |        2 |
|        Hall |    2 |  3 |                        7.00x3.00x2.00 |    1 | P.RFT | 12500 |  12500 |        3 |
|        Hall |    2 |  4 |                            shdjh test |    1 | P.RFT | 12500 |  12500 |        4 |
```

---

**ORIGINAL RESPONSE**

Note as you didn't supply the sample data my columns aren't all varchar so I have resorted to using CONCAT(...,'') to convert each non-varchar column to varchar. Refer to a demonstartion here: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e2e50/1)

**Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Ihavethistable
    ([SrNo] int, [Description] varchar(17), [Specs] varchar(12), [Qnty] int, [Unit] varchar(5), [Rate] int, [Amount] int, [AreaOfUsage] varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO Ihavethistable
    ([SrNo], [Description], [Specs], [Qnty], [Unit], [Rate], [Amount], [AreaOfUsage])
VALUES
    (1, 'bed as per...', 'test iu', 1, 'P.RFT', 35000, 35000, 'Bedroom'),
    (2, 'coffee table...', 'shdjh test', 1, 'P.RFT', 12500, 12500, 'Hall'),
    (3, 'day bed as per...', 'day bed test', 1, 'P.RFT', 19630, 19630, 'Bedroom')
;
```

**Query**:

```
select
      case when ca.rn = 2 then concat(t.srNo,'') else '' end srNo
    , ca.description
    , case when ca.rn = 2 then concat(t.Qnty,'') else '' end Qnty
    , case when ca.rn = 2 then concat(t.Unit,'') else '' end Unit
    , case when ca.rn = 2 then concat(t.Rate,'') else '' end Rate
    , case when ca.rn = 2 then concat(t.Amount,'') else '' end Amount
from Ihavethistable t
CROSS APPLY (
  VALUES
     (1, AreaOfUsage),
     (2, Description),
     (3, Specs)
  ) ca (rn, description)
order by t.srNo, ca.rn
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e2e50/1/0)**:

```
| srNo |       description | Qnty |  Unit |  Rate | Amount |
|------|-------------------|------|-------|-------|--------|
|      |           Bedroom |      |       |       |        |
|    1 |     bed as per... |    1 | P.RFT | 35000 |  35000 |
|      |           test iu |      |       |       |        |
|      |              Hall |      |       |       |        |
|    2 |   coffee table... |    1 | P.RFT | 12500 |  12500 |
|      |        shdjh test |      |       |       |        |
|      |           Bedroom |      |       |       |        |
|    3 | day bed as per... |    1 | P.RFT | 19630 |  19630 |
|      |      day bed test |      |       |       |        |
```

Comment: This is not what i want. kindly see my required output. Need to show product in groups Eg. All Bedroom product comes one by one then All Hall product come one by one and so on..

Comment: That order is obvious to you but not to me. (The expected result image has data in it that does not exist in the sample data image.) Also I  had to create the sample data, i am not great at transciption. In future you should supply the sample data in a form we can reuse.

Comment: CREATE TABLE Product
    ([SrNo] int, [Description] varchar(17), [Size] varchar(100), [Specs] varchar(12), [Qnty] int, [Unit] varchar(5), [Rate] int, [Amount] int, [AreaOfUsage] varchar(7))
;

Comment: INSERT INTO Product
    ([SrNo], [Description],[Size], [Specs], [Qnty], [Unit], [Rate], [Amount], [AreaOfUsage])
VALUES
    (1, 'Bed as per design and detail', 'test iu','7.00x4.00x2.00', 1, 'P.RFT', 35000, 35000, 'Bedroom'),
    (2, 'Coffee Table as per design and detail', 'shdjh test','7.00x3.00x2.00', 1, 'P.RFT', 12500, 12500, 'Hall'),
    (3, 'Day Bed as per design in white', 'day bed test','7.00x5.00x3.00', 1, 'P.RFT', 19630, 19630, 'Bedroom')
;

Comment: Here is the table with data. we need to use this table only to get required output.

Comment: only add sample data to the question, not comments so that others may use it or read it easily. using comments under n answer buries this too far down and cannot be read due to lack of format control.

Comment: Revised answer provided.